# PHP While loop inside function with return

Tags: php, mysql, function, while-loop, return

I have a problem with my solution, the result of my while statement doesn't show up.

I have example of this:

```
function my_function(){

    $str = '<div class="my_div">';

    $con = mysqli_connect('host','user','password','database');

    $sql = "SELECT cola, colb FROM table";
    $sql_result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($con));

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_result)){
        $vara = $row['cola'];
        $varb = $row['colb'];
        ...

        $str .= 'My text:'.$vara.$varb.'';
    }

    $str .= '</div>';

    return $str;
    mysqli_close($con);

}
```

As result I got only:

```
<div class="my_div"></div>
```

Why? How can I display the data from database (MySQL)?

Thanks for help!

Comment: FYI :  `mysqli_close($con)` should be before return!

Comment: Are you sure the query is returning any result?

Comment: Might be you may have no records in the table.

Comment: if `table` is only a representative value of your table name, this could be a variable scope issue. and we don't know how you're calling that function.

Comment: If or die(mysqli_error($con)) is not triggering and the statement is valid then no results are being returned.

Comment: If you have found a solution to a problem, you **can** give a self-answer. Deleting post wastes the times of others who are working on an answers to your questions. I was about to post an answer to your most recent post before you decied to delete it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table name is a reserved word in MySQL.

From,

```
$sql = "SELECT cola, colb FROM table";
```

To,

```
$sql = "SELECT cola, colb FROM `table`";
```

Notice the back ticks.

**Reading Material**

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html